# Не применяется transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, transition

Всем привет, есть вот такой таб. Почему-то для основного текста не применяется свойство transition. При переключении на другую вкладку. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("tabs__items");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("tabs__link");


for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.advantages__tabs {
    display: flex;  
    border: 2px solid #30d5c8;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 450px;
    flex: 0 1 50%;
}
.tabs__items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.tabs__link {
    align-items: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #3b96df;
    padding: 20px;

    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.tabs__link.active {
    color: #18d1c2;
}
.tabs__body {
    margin: auto 0;
}
.tabs__block {
    display: none;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.tabs__block:target {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    
    transition: all 1s ease 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="advantages-content">
   <div class="advantages__tabs">
       <nav class="tabs__items" id="tabs__items">
          <a href="#tab_01" class="tabs__link active">Первое преимущество</a>
          <a href="#tab_02" class="tabs__link">Второе преимущество</a>
          <a href="#tab_03" class="tabs__link">Третье преимущество</a>
          <a href="#tab_04" class="tabs__link">Четвертое преимущество</a>
          <a href="#tab_05" class="tabs__link">Пятое преимущество</a>
       </nav>
   <div class="tabs__body">
       <div id="tab_01" class="tabs__block">Первая вкладка. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam enim similique reiciendis earum, ipsa quo. Atque quas, illo asperiores sequi corporis animi deleniti veritatis, nam dignissimos eaque
        </div>
        <div id="tab_02" class="tabs__block">Вторая вкладка. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        </div>
        <div id="tab_03" class="tabs__block">Третья вкладка. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam enim similique reiciendis earum, ipsa quo. Atque quas, illo asperiores sequi corporis animi deleniti veritatis, nam dignissimos eaque, optio adipisci!
        </div>
        <div id="tab_04" class="tabs__block">Четвертая вкладка
        </div>
        <div id="tab_05" class="tabs__block">Пятая вкладка. 
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Для `.tabs__link` всё работает, а у `.tabs__block` нет анимируемых свойств.

Comment: Есть у .tabs__block:target анимируемое свойство. Если его переставить просто в .tabs__block тоже не работает.

Comment: и какое же свойство там может изменяться и главное - как это должно выглядеть, что должно происходить?

Comment: При нажатии на преимущество, плавно появляется текст. Вот так хотелось бы)

Comment: вот, это сразу в вопрос добавлять нужно, чтобы не пришлось выпытывать.

Comment: Ну я и написал) При изменении вкладки не применяется transition к основному тектсу

Comment: Немного изменил условие)

Comment: _"В чем может быть проблема?"_ Проблема в том, что свойство `display` **неанимируемое**, т.е. у него есть только устойчивые состояния, либо *none*, либо любое другое. Оно не может быть на 50% *flex*-ом. А другие свойства Вы не добавляли в `.tabs__block:target`, поэтому ничего и не происходит, а текст появляется и пропадает резко.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const btnContainer = document.getElementById("tabs__items");
const btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("tabs__link");


for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const current = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  });
}
```

```css
.advantages__tabs {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid #30d5c8;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}

.tabs__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tabs__link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #3b96df;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.tabs__link.active {
  color: #18d1c2;
}

.tabs__body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs__block {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0) translate(0px, 0px);
  transform-origin: left top;
  
  transition-property: opacity, transform, max-height;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.tabs__block:target {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="advantages-content">
  <div class="advantages__tabs">
    <nav class="tabs__items" id="tabs__items">
      <a href="#tab_01" class="tabs__link active">Первое преимущество</a>
      <a href="#tab_02" class="tabs__link">Второе преимущество</a>
      <a href="#tab_03" class="tabs__link">Третье преимущество</a>
      <a href="#tab_04" class="tabs__link">Четвертое преимущество</a>
      <a href="#tab_05" class="tabs__link">Пятое преимущество</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="tabs__body">
      <div id="tab_01" class="tabs__block">Первая вкладка. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam enim similique reiciendis earum, ipsa quo. Atque quas, illo asperiores sequi corporis animi deleniti veritatis, nam dignissimos eaque
      </div>
      <div id="tab_02" class="tabs__block">Вторая вкладка. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </div>
      <div id="tab_03" class="tabs__block">Третья вкладка. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam enim similique reiciendis earum, ipsa quo. Atque quas, illo asperiores sequi corporis animi deleniti veritatis, nam dignissimos eaque, optio adipisci!
      </div>
      <div id="tab_04" class="tabs__block">Четвертая вкладка
      </div>
      <div id="tab_05" class="tabs__block">Пятая вкладка.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Плюсую только за попытку. Я поначалу стал разбирать код, но сразу понял, что это потеря времени, ибо *такое* право на жизнь не имеет, и будет жёстко переписано в дальнейшем))

Comment: я не про ваш код, а об авторском коде в целом. Насмотрятся "курсов" на YouTube до половины, накопируют рандомных кусков кода... Самое главное, что не думают, но зато спорят. Печально всё это...

Comment: @UModeL вот сейчас вроде вообще нормально, анимацию исчезания только через keyframes можно прикрутить

Comment: по-хорошему нужно делать с *relative/absolute* и просто менять видимость блоков через *opacity*.

Comment: @UModeL https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1198932/331312 тут без absolute